# How can I use Regexp to rename files in Dired mode?

Tags: dired, regular-expressions

I've have some videos (.mp4) with subtitles files (.SRT) that I need to rename. These files have long names so I can only rename them manually. I've tried Python to rename them, but it fails.

I've tried to rename it with Spacemacs and I did it using Dired `SPC f j` to open the folder and renamed the files going line by line: Select the line, go after the number of the video and then deleting till the dot of the extension, I created a simple macro that do this and then ran the macro on all the files in that folder.

I would like to do it with a regexp, so that I can also learn about it.

The folder looks like this in Dired:

```
total used in directory 477255 available 38636028
drwxrwxrwx  1 User None     28672 02-23 19:04 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 User None      8192 02-23 19:02 .
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None  30019832 02-23 13:13 010 Introduction to Global Economics.mp4
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None      8514 02-23 13:13 010 Introduction to Global Economics-subtitle-en.srt
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None    263198 02-23 13:13 011 BLS-Unemployment.pdf
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None 108247504 02-23 13:13 011 The International Monetary Fund GDP.mp4
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None     28101 02-23 13:14 011 The International Monetary Fund GDP-subtitle-en.srt
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None  35996597 02-23 13:14 012 Excel Exercise 1 Analyzing IMF GDP Data.mp4
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None     11454 02-23 12:17 012 Excel Exercise 1 Analyzing IMF GDP Data-subtitle-en.srt
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None  37911096 02-23 13:15 012 Exercise-1.xlsx
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None 104361394 02-23 13:15 013 Excel Exercise 1 Part 1 of 3.mp4
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None     37892 02-23 13:11 013 Excel Exercise 1 Part 1 of 3-subtitle-en.srt
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None  77650639 02-23 13:13 014 Excel Exercise 1 Part 2 of 3.mp4
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None     32563 02-23 13:13 014 Excel Exercise 1 Part 2 of 3-subtitle-en.srt
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None  94068512 02-23 13:14 015 Excel Exercise 1 Part 3 of 3.mp4
-rw-rw-rw-  1 User None     34325 02-23 13:14 015 Excel Exercise 1 Part 3 of 3-subtitle-en.srt
```

I want to rename the file: `010 Introduction to Global Economics.mp4` to `010.mp4` and `010 Introduction to Global Economics-subtitle-en.srt` to `010.srt`. Also, there are some other files that should not be renamed.

Till now, I tried this `\b[0-9]\{3\}\b\( w*\)+.mp4` and it selects the `.mp4` files, but how can I then tell it to keep the number of the video?

Edit:
All the videos and subtitle files number have always 3 digits, from 001 to 252.

Comment: Have you tried using `* m` and `* r` commands in dired to rename with regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

Found out, by trial and error that this works: `\(\b[0-9]\{3\}\b\)\( w*\)*.*\(.mp4\|.srt\)` and replace it by `\1\3`.

Comment: You'll be interested to learn that you can edit filenames in dired buffers directly (e.g. update all files with a regular search and replace) after enabling `wdired` with using the normal "toggle read only" binding (`C-x C-q` -- but you seem to be using spacemacs, so it might be different).  This is usually more convenient than using a keyboard macro.

Comment: To add to @phils comment, if you are using vanilla Emacs or alike (without massive modifications, the dired opens by default in read-only mode, to toggle that, either use `C-x -C-q` as @phils said, or if you don't know the keybinding, run `read-only-mode` in command in the minibuffer to toggle the read-only mode, then do the changes you want, and then `C-x C-s` to save the changes. More explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15882553/1613005

Answer (score 0):

In spacemacs you can use the key combinations in the other comments, or you can do `SPC SPC dired-toggle-read-only` to enter edit mode. Once completed, you can use `SPC SPC wdired-finish-edit` to complete, or `SPC SPC wdired-abort-changes` to abort. Once in edit mode, you can used good'ol `:%s/replace this/with this/gc` kind of thing to rename your files.